# How to make a new clone command or add clone options in Gerrit?

Tags: git, gerrit, git-clone

The download-commands plugin makes a few very useful commands available for cloning repository and fetching patches. As for clone commands, it gives `clone` and `clone with commit-msg hook`.

However, I would like to either add a new clone command or add options to the clone commands to simplify some operations. For example, `clone -b` or `clone --recurse-submodules` or any other added options for `git clone`. Is this supported? If so, how would I do this?

Comment: Unfortunately I think this is not possible.

Comment: Alright. If that's the case, since I have lots of free time these days, I will look into extending download-commands with that functionality

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not currently possible

Someone will have to extend the existing plugin or develop a new one for this feature to be possible.